# Get a single value from JSON object

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, object

I have an object or array (not sure how to call it) returned to jQuery from JSON. When I try to print it with `console.log(pData)`, I get the following:

[image]

Is it possible to somehow print only the value of address? I want to assign it to a variable and use somewhere else. Thanks.

Comment: try `pData[0][0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do `pData[0][0].Address` or `pData[0][0]['Address']`

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks!